# Implementing ActionBarSherlock, gradle error

Tags: android, dependencies, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I'm a starter at android developing and am currently really stuck with implementing actionbarsherlock. I know this has been discussed before, but I'm getting really confused regarding dependencies and how to set up the project structure. I tried following all the instructions, but it's not working out. I keep getting a different problem with the gradle. I'm using Android Studio 0.2.0.

My current error says:

```
>Gradle 'MyAppProject' project refresh failed:
>Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip".
>Error: Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':MyApp'.
>Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>A problem occurred configuring project ':Libraries:ActionBarSherlock'.
>Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>Main Manifest missing from C:\Users\JJ2\AndroidStudioProjects\MyAppProject\Libraries\ActionBarSherlock\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

My project is build as follows:

```
-MyAppProject
|+.idea
|+gradle
|-Libraries
||-ActionBarSherlock
|||+gen
|||+libs
|||+res
|||-src
||||-android.support.v4.app
|||||-Watson
||||+com.actionbarsherlock
|||-ActionBarSherlock.iml
|||-AndroidManifest.xml
|||-build.gradle
|||-lint.xml
|||-pom.xml
|||-project.properties
|||-README.md
|-MyApp
||+build
||+libs
||-src
|||-main
||||-java
|||||+com.mywebsite.myapp
||||+res
||||-AndroidManifest.xml
||||-ic_launcher-web.png
||-build.gradle
||-MyApp.iml
|-build.gradle
|-gradlew
|-gradlew.bat
|-local.properties
|-settings.gradle
|-MyAppProject.iml
-External Libraries
|-<Android 4.2.2>
||+android.jar
||+annotations.jar
||+res
```

The content of the build.gradle in the MyAppProject directory:

```
task assemble{}
```

The build.gradle in the MyApp directory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(":Libraries:ActionBarSherlock")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle in the Libraries\ActionBarSherlock directory:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
}
```

Lastly, my Project Structure looks as follows:

Modules

```
-ActionBarSherlock (Dependencies: Android 4.2.2, [v]android-support-v4)
    -Android
-MyApp             (Dependencies: Android 4.2.2, [ ]ActionBarSherlock)
    -Android
    -Android-Gradle
-MyAppProject      (Dependencies: Android 4.2.2)
    -Android-Gradle
```

Libraries

```
None
```

Global Libraries

```
-android-support-v4 (Classes: ...\MyAppProject\MyApp\libs\android-support-v4.jar)
```

I hope somebody can notice anything wrong with the code, although a lot of people seem to have uresolved issues since the new Android Studio release.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Top directory settings.gradle:**

```
include ':MyApp', ':Libraries:ActionBarSherlock'
```

include any other libs you may enter to your project

**Top directory build.gradle:**
its okay with task assemble {}

**Actionbar sherlock build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

**Also, IN ALL .gradle files that gradle version is set:**
replace everywhere the gradle version to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
```

Android Studio 2.x uses gradle 0.5.x, and by using `+` you 'll keep your gradle up to date (they updated it before 2 days, and we have frequent updates!! )

Your gradle settings now will be okay!
**Note1:**
Any other erros may occur from iml./idea files ... You can try changing them in Studio's project settings, eg set source files for each module(sherlock, MyApp), their libraries, etc!

**Note 2:**
Also if you are using some other libraries, which requires higher version of SDK than your app, you can get an error, w/o explanation!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I forgot to include the settings.gradle content, which was like you described. The other remarks were probably necessary indeed. Unfortunately, I started messing with the Project Settings->Gradle and now I keep getting an error message saying:
Gradle 'WallPainterProject' project refresh failed: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'. Gradle distribution 'C:\Users\JJ2\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.6-bin\72srdo3a5eb3bic159kar72vok' contains too many directories. Expected to find exactly 1 directory.

Comment: I can't seem to find an example of a proper set up for the gradle properties. I would be very grateful if you, or someone else, could post an example of a normal set up and of the directory where the gradle is located.
And I would give you a +1, but I haven't collected enough karma myself yet haha.

Comment: you are welcome! To have a normal setup, just create an new empty project, with the .gradle changes i posted above. I faced some problems with gradle installation(it didnt completely download the gradle binaries)... I went to that directory you wrote, and deleted some lock and corrupted files! Go here: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip, download it, and go to the gradle1.6-bin/72 ..../ directory, and then paste it, and extract it! Does it work now?

Comment: Well I just deleted everything and reinstalled android studio, and now the gradle errors are gone:). However, I'm getting a 'install parse failed inconsistent certificates' error, when I try to run the app on my phone, even though I already deleted the app from there. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well apparently the app was not in the app drawer anymore, but still in settings->apps. Anyway, I did everything you told me to and it all worked out! Thank again!!

Comment: When you say :Libraries:ActionBarSherlock, is there an actual Libraries folder that houses ActionBarSherlock?  Or is that symbolic?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, yes, there is an actual folder that contains ABS. Also, make sure to include the correct folder of ABS repository into your code! ( its not the root folder of ABS repo)